# xml parsing jquery - how to extract individual values from repeating XML tags with different attributes

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

So i'm trying to just get a value extracted from my XML, the whole code (well almost but the general idea) is on jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/TQzkj/4/

All i'm trying to do is to extract the value of Option Value=1 from the XML which is Tops

```
        xml = '<Set>    <Question>        
        <QuestionId>278</QuestionId>

        <Option Value='1'>Tops</Option>
        <Option Value='2'>Skirts</Option>
        <Option Value='3'>Shoes</Option>        </Question>    <Points>0</Points>      
        <BarHide>8</BarHide></Set>';
```

i'm using the following code

[Code]

```
$(xml).find( "Question" ).each(
function(){
    var item = $(this), 
    id =  item.find('QuestionId').text();

    if(id==="278"){
        var option = item.find('Option');
        var itemid = option.attr('Value');

        if(itemid === "1"){
            $("#button1").attr("value", option[0]); //this is the line that is wrong and needs fixing
        }
    }
    //itemid =  item.attr('id');
}
```

);

[/Code]

When I debug the value option I see 3 elements and I see the text that I need in textContext but I don't know how to extract them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an array, jQuery's `find()` returns a set of elements in an object, so just do:

```
$("#button1").val(option.text());
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TQzkj/5/)